# Is it possible to close prettyphoto modal inside iframe?

Tags: jquery, iframe, lightbox

I'm using prettyphoto jquery plugin for lightbox.
When somebody clicks on a link it opens a lightbox iframe.
Inside the iframe there is button that should close the lightbox.
in documentation there is a code:

```
$.prettyPhoto.close();
```

But don't how to use it properly. So, how to close a lightbox inside iframe.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since it's in an iframe, it doesn't have access to the same scope that your prettyPhoto plugin is running in.

Assuming the iframe is on the same domain, you can traverse upwards into the parent, and call the function there.

`window.parent.$.prettyPhoto.close();` would likely do the trick.